# MySql vs MariaDB index query

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

I have a mysql database 5.1.73-0 ubuntu0.10.04.1-log that run this sentence in 0,1 s :

```
select  date_format(if(isnull(acctstoptime),CURDATE(),acctstoptime),
               '%Y-%m-%d') as fecha ,count(*
                   )
    from  radacct
    where  radacct.username like '%_ins_98\_%'
      and  ((acctstoptime)>=
              ( SELECT  max(fFecNav)+ INTERVAL 1 day as fFecNav
                    from  swb_NavegaDias
                    where  idInstalacion=98
              )
              or  isnull(acctstoptime)
           )
    group by  if(isnull(acctstoptime),CURDATE(),date(acctstoptime))
    order by  acctstoptime;
```

explain:

```
 id     select_type     table               type            possible_keys   key key_len     ref     rows    Extra
 1      PRIMARY         radacct range       acctstoptime    acctstoptime    9                       8646    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
 2      SUBQUERY        swb_NavegaDias      ALL                                                     54400   Using where
```

Then I do a mysql dump and update on MariaDB 10.1.8-MariaDB-log CentOS7

and same query takes 5 seconds to execute.

Explain

```
 id     select_type     table               type            possible_keys   key key_len     ref     rows    Extra
 1  PRIMARY         radacct             ALL             acctstoptime                            4621901 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
 2  SUBQUERY        swb_NavegaDias      ALL                                                     53946   Using where
```

The problema is whith the subquery, that executed single takes 0,06s but makes slow the main one.

```
 select max(fFecNav)+ INTERVAL 1 day as fFecNav from swb_NavegaDias where idInstalacion=98;
```

If I change the main query without subquery it takes 0,1s:

```
select  date_format(if(isnull(acctstoptime),CURDATE(),acctstoptime),
               '%Y-%m-%d') as fecha ,count(*
                   )
    from  radacct
    where  radacct.username like '%_ins_98\_%'
      and  ((acctstoptime)>= '2015-12-20'
              or  isnull(acctstoptime)
           )
    group by  if(isnull(acctstoptime),CURDATE(),date(acctstoptime))
    order by  acctstoptime;
```

Table definition are exactly the same on both databases .. because i've done a mysql dump.

I've tryed ANALYZE TABLE, force indexs but none makes run the query like with mysql.

What else i can check ?

**** EDITED ***

I've tryed with SQL_NO_CACHE and same results.

The tables are exactly the same as i have donne a full restore of the database.

Show create table Mysql:

```
 CREATE TABLE `radacct` (
   `radacctid` bigint(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `acctsessionid` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `acctuniqueid` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `groupname` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `realm` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
   `nasipaddress` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `nasportid` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `nasporttype` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctstarttime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctstoptime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctsessiontime` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctauthentic` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `connectinfo_start` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `connectinfo_stop` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctinputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctoutputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `calledstationid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL   DEFAULT '',
   `callingstationid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `acctterminatecause` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `servicetype` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `framedprotocol` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `framedipaddress` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `acctstartdelay` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctstopdelay` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
   `xascendsessionsvrkey` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`radacctid`),
   KEY `framedipaddress` (`framedipaddress`),
   KEY `acctsessionid` (`acctsessionid`),
   KEY `acctsessiontime` (`acctsessiontime`),
   KEY `acctuniqueid` (`acctuniqueid`),
   KEY `acctstarttime` (`acctstarttime`),
   KEY `acctstoptime` (`acctstoptime`),
   KEY `nasipaddress` (`nasipaddress`),
   KEY `username` (`username`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8162219 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And Show Create table MariaDB:

```
 CREATE TABLE `radacct` (
    `radacctid` bigint(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `acctsessionid` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `acctuniqueid` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `groupname` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `realm` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
    `nasipaddress` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `nasportid` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `nasporttype` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `acctstarttime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `acctstoptime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `acctsessiontime` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
    `acctauthentic` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `connectinfo_start` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `connectinfo_stop` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `acctinputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `acctoutputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `calledstationid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `callingstationid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `acctterminatecause` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `servicetype` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `framedprotocol` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `framedipaddress` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `acctstartdelay` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
    `acctstopdelay` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
    `xascendsessionsvrkey` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`radacctid`),
    KEY `framedipaddress` (`framedipaddress`),
    KEY `acctsessionid` (`acctsessionid`),
    KEY `acctsessiontime` (`acctsessiontime`),
    KEY `acctuniqueid` (`acctuniqueid`),
    KEY `acctstarttime` (`acctstarttime`),
    KEY `acctstoptime` (`acctstoptime`),
    KEY `nasipaddress` (`nasipaddress`),
    KEY `username` (`username`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8162213 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems there is far more data in the MariaDB table. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi Patrick, the data is exactly the same. Just dump from mysql and restore to mariadb. So same rows on both databases.

Comment: Oops, read over that bit. What is weird is that the number of rows in the MySQL explain are 8646 and 54400, while the MariaDB explain mentions 4621901 and 53946.

Comment: Yes in fact mysql is on production so there is some more rows adding time to time on it (54400 vs 53946). MariaDB is on a new server, faster. The other value is because mysql uses index and search into 8646 rows and MariaDB is not using index and search all over the table.

Comment: Is it possible you're getting super-fast query results on your old server because of caching? Try `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE whatever` on both servers; make sure you're measuring query time accurately. Also, please show us the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE` from your new server for all the tables involved in the query. My theory is that the indexes might not be set up the same.

Comment: If possible, let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for 5.1 as well.

Comment: Notice (in the EXPLAIN) that 5.1 used an index; 10.1 did not.  That, not the subquery, is the root of the difference.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. SQL_NO_CACHE same results.I've just update with show create table. Thanks